# Mongo create new field by mapping value from one field to value in a field in another collection

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection c1 with a value like `{'Race': 'blck'}` and I want to use another collection c2 with fields `{'raw': 'blck', 'mapped_race': 'black'}` to update the document in c1 with a new field like `{'Race_Standardized': 'black'}`. This would be accomplished by matching the value of Race in c1 to the document in c2 on the raw value.

Update would make c1 document have fields `{'Race': 'blck', 'Race_Standardized': black'}`.

How do I go about doing this in an aggregation pipeline? (I'm working in PyMongo.)

Comment: it is not possible with aggregation pipeline, it requires 2 separate queries for find from c2 and update in c1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be more efficient to query the c2 collection and iterate the documents on the client side to build a bulk write operation for c1:

```
updates = []
for doc in db.c2.find({}):
   updates.append(pymongo.UpdateMany({'Race':doc.get('raw')},{'$set':{'Race_Standardized':doc.get('mapped_race')}}))
result = db.c1.bulk_write(updates)
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do it:

```
db.c1.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "c2",
            localField: "Race",
            foreignField: "raw",
            as: "Race_Standardized"
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            Race_Standardized: {
                $first: "$Race_Standardized.mapped_race"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "c1"
    }
])
```

but keep in mind that the $out stage will overwrite the c1 collection.

Comment: If you are using MongoDB 4.2+ use `$merge` instead of `$out`

Answer (score 0):

Since Mongo is a nosql DB there is no join like we have in relational db. However this is overcome by the $lookup feature within the aggregate pipeline. I am yet to try this out within a pymongo framework but in mongo you will have to use a combination of $lookup , $unwind and the $out to update the field. The $lookup will be like a left out join in SQL world and that returns an array - we have to use $unwind to get the specific field and then $out to update back or write to a new collection. I found this link helpful [https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/update-a-collection-field-based-on-another-collection/4875]